# Rendering LaTeX in output cells in Colaboratory

Tags: latex, jupyter, mathjax, google-colaboratory

I expect a cell like

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
display(Math(r"e^\alpha"))
```

to render with MathJax as it does in normal jupyter,
but instead it just displays latex code like:

```
$$e^\alpha$$
```

Is there a way to get Colaboratory to render it correctly? (It manages it fine for text cells).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplify scraaappy's answer a bit.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Math
display(HTML("<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/"
             "latest.js?config=default'></script>"))
Math(r"e^\alpha")
```

It just includes `MathJax` library so the following equations can be displayed.

Or use the built-in `output._publish` (Aug 2018)

```
from IPython.display import Math
from google.colab.output._publish import javascript
url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/latest.js?config=default"

javascript(url=url)
Math(r"e^\alpha")
```

Instead of CDN, you can also use MathJax that comes with Colab.
`https://colab.research.google.com/static/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=default`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that it's the right method,but it works:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, Math
display(Javascript("var sc = document.createElement('script')"))
display(Javascript("sc.type='text/javascript'; sc.src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML&dummy=.js'"))
display(Javascript("var currentDiv = document.activeElement.parent"))
#display(Javascript("sc.onload = function () {console.log('loaded')};"))
display(Javascript("document.body.insertBefore(sc, currentDiv)"))
display(Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'))
display(Math(r"e^\alpha"))
```

Comment: I just realized that we don't need to import `display`, it's imported by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround, you can define your own equation rendering function:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Math
def mview(e):
  display(HTML("<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/"
         "latest.js?config=default'></script>"))
  return Math(latex(e))
```

And then use it as follows:

```
e = Integral(cos(x)**2, (x, 0, pi))
mview(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you question is uncorrect, it should be "inline" not output in colaboratory.

Second to answer your question, just change "Code" option in menu bar to "Markdown" and executive `$= e^\alpha$` or `$$= e^\alpha$$` in "In box".

This is example
[colab show latex in mardown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH366.jpg)

Update: Sorry for my late update, i saw in colaboratory notebook so difference
, to show LaTeX in it, just Insert "text cell" in Insert menu bar and executive `$$= e^\alpha$$` or `$= e^\alpha$` in input box

Comment: I assume you mean code cell. Even so it doesn't work in Colaboratory. In any case that doesn't answer the question, I want to be able to produce latex from python and have that rendered.

Comment: @SeanD I saw in Google Colaboratory so difference, so I have updated to answer  for your question.

Comment: Thanks for trying. As I mentioned in the question I have no problem rendering latex from text cells, the problem is to render a latex string that I have as a python variable.

Comment: This is a wrong answer - the OP is looking for **code** output, *not* **text** output.

Answer (score 1):

**For Those Using HandCalc**

I ended up doing something a bit different but in the end solved this issue:

```
from IPython.display import Math
```

Next, in your handcalc cell:

```
%%capture texres
%%tex 2
YOUR CODE HERE
```

and in the next cell afterwards:

`Math(texres.stdout[3:-3])`

this should work (sort of) like using Handcalc in Jupyterlab

Enjoy.