# Latex output from sympy does not correctly display in Google Colaboratory Jupyter notebooks

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using Google's Colaboratory platform to run python in a Jupyter notebook.  In standard Jupyter notebooks, the output of sympy functions is correctly typeset Latex, but the Colaboratory notebook just outputs the Latex, as in the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
x=sp.symbols('x')
a=sp.Integral(sp.sin(x)*sp.exp(x),x);a
```

results in Latex output like this:

```
$$\int e^{x} \sin{\left (x \right )}\, dx$$
```

The answer cited in these questions, [Rendering LaTeX in output cells in Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573644/rendering-latex-in-output-cells-in-colaboratory) and [LaTeX equations do not render in google Colaboratory when using IPython.display.Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856683/latex-equations-do-not-render-in-google-colaboratory-when-using-ipython-display) doesn't fix the problem. While it provides a method to display Latex expressions in the output of a code cell, it doesn't fix the output from the built-in sympy functions.

Any suggestions on how to get sympy output to properly render?  Or is this a problem with the Colaboratory notebook?

Answer (score 10):

I have just made this code snippet to make sympy works like a charm in colab.research.googlr.com !!!

```
def custom_latex_printer(exp,**options):
    from google.colab.output._publish import javascript
    url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/latest.js?config=default"
    javascript(url=url)
    return sympy.printing.latex(exp,**options)
init_printing(use_latex="mathjax",latex_printer=custom_latex_printer)
```

Put it after you imported sympy
This one basically tell sympy to embed mathjax library using colab api before they actually output any syntax.

Comment: NameError: name 'init_printing' is not defined. What should I do to not obtain this error message?

Comment: @vesszabo `from sympy import init_printing` on the top

Comment: This answer works perfectly with sympy 1.1.1 in google colab as of 2019-10-04, but upgrading sympy to 1.4 appears to stop it from working.

Comment: user1228770 is right. Upgrading to sympy 1.4 makes this solution to stop working. Any comments on why this is happening?

Comment: could you successfully display equation in display mode ? I can only get inline mode even for sympy results alone

Answer (score 3):

You need to include MathJax library before display. Set it up in a cell like this first.

```
from google.colab.output._publish import javascript
url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/latest.js?config=default"
```

Later, you include `javascript(url=url)` before displaying:

```
x=sp.symbols('x')
a=sp.Integral(sp.sin(x)*sp.exp(x),x)
javascript(url=url)
a
```

Then, it will display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using colab's mathjax and setting the configuration file to TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML worked for me. Below is the code:

```
from sympy          import init_printing
from sympy.printing import latex

def colab_LaTeX_printer(exp, **options):  
    from google.colab.output._publish import javascript 

    url_ = "https://colab.research.google.com/static/mathjax/MathJax.js?"
    cfg_ = "config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML" # "config=default"

    javascript(url=url_+cfg_)

    return latex(exp, **options)
# end of def

init_printing(use_latex="mathjax", latex_printer=colab_LaTeX_printer)
```